# When did ".NET" get dropped from the name of Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, history, naming

I was reading the installation guide of a development tool today, and it claimed to support the IDE named "Visual Studio .NET 2010 Professional, Premium, or Ultimate".

Isn't it true that the ".NET" mention in the "Visual Studio" product name was dropped after 2003?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Version_history

Looks like after VS 2003:

Visual Studio 2005, codenamed Whidbey (a reference to Whidbey Island in Puget Sound), was released online in October 2005 and to retail stores a few weeks later. Microsoft removed the ".NET" moniker from Visual Studio 2005 (as well as every other product with .NET in its name), but it still primarily targets the .NET Framework, which was upgraded to version 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

My box for Visual Studio 2008 Pro does not have .NET in the title anywhere. The box for 2005 pro doesn't have it in the title either.  I don't have a 2003 or 2010 box to check.